# Highcharts Progress Bar Chart

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to create a progress chart in Highcharts like this:

https://0.s3.envato.com/files/84221450/screenshots/weblator_responsive_charts_7_bootstrap.jpg

I believe a bar chart can be customized to create this. But is it possible to change the styling so that no axes are showing and the bar labels are positioned above the bars rather than preceding them?

Comment: progress bar below is not acceptable. Comment what more is to be done. If you want put those pattern inside bar of chart , then this is beyond current scope

Answer (score 4):

Possible to recreate but it is not so dynamic( in style ). So you have to adjust `css` according to data series in chart.

```js
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'bar',

    marginBottom: 120
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  colors: ['#173c64'],
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['option 1', 'option 2', 'option 3', 'option 4 ', 'option 5 '],
    labels: {
      align: 'left',
      x: 5,
      y: -20, /* to be adjusted according to number of bars*/
      style: {
       fontSize: "1rem",
        color: '#000'
      }
    },
    lineWidth: 0,
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    lineColor: 'transparent',
    minorTickLength: 0,
    tickLength: 0,
    title: {
      enabled: false
    }

  },
  yAxis: {
    lineWidth: 0,
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    lineColor: 'transparent',
    labels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    minorTickLength: 0,
    tickLength: 0,
    title: {
      enabled: false
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      stacking: "normal",
      //groupPadding: 0, //add here
      //pointPadding: 0, //add here,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    margin: 0,
    useHTML: true,
    text: "Test",
    style: {
      "color": "#333333",
      "fontSize": "1.5rem",
      "fontWeight": "bold"
    }
  },

  series: [{
    data: [{
      y: 100,
      color: '#99ddff'
    }, {
      y: 10,
      color: '#ff8c1a'
    }, {
      y: 20,
      color: '#ff471a'
    }, {
      y: 60,
      color: '#c299ff'
    }, {
      y: 10,
      color: '#99ddff'
    }]
  }]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```