# Making Highcharts look like progress bar with more than one series

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts, bar-chart

I have been trying to modify the look of highcharts bars and I have managed to make the horizontal bar charts to look like progress bar charts. I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42871005/142600) here in SO in order to do that. Right now, I am having two problems with this. The chart looks fine if I have one data series but here is how it looks if I have more than one series (there can be up to 3 series).

[image]

Therefore, I want to increase the margin between the labels (USA, Japan etc). Secondly, I would like to align the data labels (10, 40, 20 etc) towards the right of the chart, outside the bars. I think I need to write some javascript but I am not sure where to start or what to modify. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
  renderTo: 'container',
  type: 'bar',
  backgroundColor: '#003755',
  marginBottom: 60,
  marginLeft: 80,
  marginTop: 40,
  marginRight: 140
  },
  colors: ['#0AA3DB', '#3AC6B1', '#000612'],
  xAxis: [{
    categories: ['USA', 'Japan', 'Canada', 'Brasil', 'China', 'Russia', 'UK', 'France', 'NA'],
    labels: {
      align: 'left',
      x: 0,
      y: -13,/* to be adjusted according to number of bars*/
      style: {
        fontSize: "0.875rem",
        color: '#fff'
      }
    },
    lineColor: 'transparent',
    tickLength: 0
  }],
  yAxis: {
    lineWidth: 0,
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    labels: {
      enabled: false
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      dataLabels: {
        allowOverlap: true,
        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
      }
    },
    series: {
      pointWidth: 8, //width of the column bars irrespective of the chart size
      borderRadius: 5,
      borderColor: 'transparent',
      pointPadding: 0,
      groupPadding: 0,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '<b>{point.y:,.0f}</b>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true,
        align: 'right'
      }
    }
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  },

  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  tooltip: {
    yDecimals: 2
  },
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
    pointFormat: '<b>{point.name} - {point.y:,.0f}%</b>',
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Current',
    type: 'bar',
    data: [{
      name: 'USA',
      y: 10
    }, {
      name: 'Japan',
      y: 40
    }, {
      name: 'Canada',
      y: 20
    }, {
      name: 'Brasil',
      y: 5
    }, {
      name: 'China',
      y: 9
    }, {
      name: 'Russia',
      y: 8
    }, {
      name: 'UK',
      y: 7
    }, {
      name: 'France',
      y: 1
    }, {
      name: 'NA',
      y: 0
    }]
  }, {
    name: '2005',
    type: 'bar',
    data: [{
      name: 'USA',
      y: 10
    }, {
      name: 'Japan',
      y: 40
    }, {
      name: 'Canada',
      y: 20
    }, {
      name: 'Brasil',
      y: 5
    }, {
      name: 'China',
      y: 9
    }, {
      name: 'Russia',
      y: 8
    }, {
      name: 'UK',
      y: 7
    }, {
      name: 'France',
      y: 1
    }, {
      name: 'NA',
      y: 0
    }]
  }, {
    name: '2023',
    type: 'bar',
    data: [{
      name: 'USA',
      y: 10
    }, {
      name: 'Japan',
      y: 40
    }, {
      name: 'Canada',
      y: 20
    }, {
      name: 'Brasil',
      y: 5
    }, {
      name: 'China',
      y: 9
    }, {
      name: 'Russia',
      y: 8
    }, {
      name: 'UK',
      y: 7
    }, {
      name: 'France',
      y: 1
    }, {
      name: 'NA',
      y: 0
    }]
  }]
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fbsveysb/

Comment: check this with [scrollbars-for-any-axis](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/news/224-scrollbars-for-any-axis/)  demo https://jsfiddle.net/8cwxmrw4/

Comment: thanks @Deep3015. It seems like I need to find a way to set the height dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupPadding`for increasing the space between column groups.

The default value of `dataLabels.align` is `left` (point on the left side of the label) - this value should be used to position data labels outside of the bars.

---

**Live working demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/w782cud7/

**API references:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.dataLabels.align
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.groupPadding

Comment: thank you for the answer. correct me if I am wrong, but it seems like the bar height is changed to fit the bars between the two data labels, instead of increasing the space between the data labels. Is that correct? If so, that is not what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: The bars need to somehow fit inside the chart, so if you want more space between the labels you need to either 1: Reduce the width of the bars as in Kamil's example, or 2: Make the chart higher as in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/w782cud7/2/  Play around with different settings for `chart.height`, `xAxis.labels.y` and `plotOptions.series.groupPadding` to get the result you want.

Comment: Thanks @Sphinxxx. I think playing with the height is the right way to go here. But as I see the relevant answers in SO, it is not really possible to  set the height dynamically. I need it because the height should be set based on the number of countries.

Comment: Maybe updating the chart with a new `height` value is the solution here: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.height

Comment: @AhmetKeskin - `chart.setSize(chart.chartWidth, myNewHeight)`

Answer (score 0):

This may be one of the possible solution as I made in comment. It uses [Scrollbars for any axis](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/news/224-scrollbars-for-any-axis/) which shows how to have scroll in axis. It uses highstock.js file, it can be applied to regular Highcharts axes.

```js
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'bar',
    backgroundColor: '#003755',
    marginBottom: 60,
    marginLeft: 80,
    marginTop: 40,
    marginRight: 140,
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var maxVal = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.series.length; i++) {
          if (Math.max.apply(Math, this.series[i].yData) > maxVal) {
            maxVal = Math.max.apply(Math, this.series[i].yData)
          }
        }
        this.yAxis[0].setExtremes(0, maxVal + 10)
      }
    }
  },
  colors: ['#0AA3DB', '#3AC6B1', '#000612'],
  xAxis: [{
    categories: ['USA', 'Japan', 'Canada', 'Brasil', 'China', 'Russia', 'UK', 'France', 'NA'],
    labels: {
      align: 'left',
      x: 0,
      y: -20,
      /* to be adjusted according to number of bars*/
      style: {
        fontSize: "0.875rem",
        color: '#fff'
      }
    },
    lineColor: 'transparent',
    tickLength: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 4,
    scrollbar: {
      enabled: true
    },
  }],
  yAxis: {
    lineWidth: 0,
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    labels: {
      enabled: false
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      grouping: true,
      pointPadding: 0,
      dataLabels: {
        allowOverlap: true,
        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
      }
    },
    series: {
      pointWidth: 8, //width of the column bars irrespective of the chart size
      borderRadius: 5,
      borderColor: 'transparent',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        //format: '{point.y:.1f}',
        format: '<b>{point.y:,.0f}</b>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true,
        overflow: 'none'
      }
    }
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  },

  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  tooltip: {
    yDecimals: 2
  },
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
    pointFormat: '<b>{point.name} - {point.y:,.0f}%</b>',
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Current',
    type: 'bar',
    data: [{
      name: 'USA',
      y: 10
    }, {
      name: 'Japan',
      y: 40
    }, {
      name: 'Canada',
      y: 20
    }, {
      name: 'Brasil',
      y: 5
    }, {
      name: 'China',
      y: 9
    }, {
      name: 'Russia',
      y: 8
    }, {
      name: 'UK',
      y: 7
    }, {
      name: 'France',
      y: 1
    }, {
      name: 'NA',
      y: 0
    }]
  }, {
    name: '2005',
    type: 'bar',
    data: [{
      name: 'USA',
      y: 10
    }, {
      name: 'Japan',
      y: 40
    }, {
      name: 'Canada',
      y: 20
    }, {
      name: 'Brasil',
      y: 5
    }, {
      name: 'China',
      y: 9
    }, {
      name: 'Russia',
      y: 8
    }, {
      name: 'UK',
      y: 7
    }, {
      name: 'France',
      y: 1
    }, {
      name: 'NA',
      y: 0
    }]
  }, {
    name: '2023',
    type: 'bar',
    data: [{
      name: 'USA',
      y: 10
    }, {
      name: 'Japan',
      y: 40
    }, {
      name: 'Canada',
      y: 20
    }, {
      name: 'Brasil',
      y: 5
    }, {
      name: 'China',
      y: 9
    }, {
      name: 'Russia',
      y: 8
    }, {
      name: 'UK',
      y: 7
    }, {
      name: 'France',
      y: 1
    }, {
      name: 'NA',
      y: 0
    }]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```